# How can I find the Point Cloud Tools in QGIS 3.34 Mac Version?

Tags: qgis, lidar, point-cloud, toolbox, laz

I just downloaded the QGIS Latest Release Version 3.34 (Prizren) for Mac to try the new Point Cloud tools, that should be natively available according to this post: https://www.lutraconsulting.co.uk/blog/2023/05/30/pointcloud-qgis-processing/

But I can't find the tools in my toolbox:

[image]

[image]

I am using the standalone installer for Mac, which I downloaded here: https://qgis.org/downloads/macos/qgis-macos-pr.dmg

I am NOT looking for a plugin, instead I am looking for these NATIVE Point Cloud Tools:

[image]

This screenshot is from the blogpost from lutraconsulting, not from my QGIS:

Edit: 02.02.2024: I am pretty sure the problem is the Mac Standalone Installer, that I used: https://qgis.org/downloads/macos/qgis-macos-pr.dmg

My colleague, who uses windows, doesn't have this problem. He can see and use the Pointcloud tools.

How can I solve the problem ? Any other download-version I could use?

Comment: They should appear below the "Plots" tools. Did you use the standalone installer or the OSGeo4W one ? Did you check in the Help>About window that you have PDAL installed, if yes witch version ?

Comment: I used the standalone installer. In the menu bar I have the "Help" section, but not "About". There are other options like "Help Contents", "Report an Issue", "Check QGIS Version", etc. ....

Comment: You may try to re-install QGIS with the OSGeo4W installer, there you can made sure that the PDAL library are installed

Comment: Why do you post a screenshot of the plugins dialog window when you state that you are **not** asking about plugins, but about QGIS native tools?

Comment: @Babel: Because there are native QGIS plugins that come with the installation. For example when you are wondering where to find the processing tools, you just have to check if the natively installed processing plugin is activated.

Comment: @RichardRasch I didn't mention OSGeo4W.... ?

Comment: @Babel, Right, You didn't. I misread the comments...

Answer (score 0):

Type 'ladar' in your processing tool box search.  The Grass lidar tools should pop-up.  Also, if you add the Whitebox Tools plug-in you will get a bunch more options.   What features are you looking for?

https://www.whiteboxgeo.com/manual/wbt_book/qgis_plugin.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am aware that there are several plugins dealing with Point Cloud data and I already tried some of them. However, I would like to access the native QGIS processing tools for Point Cloud data and I am wondering why they don't show up in my QGIS 3.34 GUI.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I just found a solution thanks to someone on GitHub. Using conda env solved the problem for me on Ubuntu.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the tools to appear on my Mac by following the intsructions to install QGIS with Macports found here: https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html#macports